# Azure Databricks query against struct array column returning all the same values

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an Azure Databricks table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE finlog 
(
    AccountNumber       STRING,
    ClientControlNumber STRING,
    LogDetails          ARRAY<STRUCT<DetailId: STRING, ControlId: STRING, Amount: STRING, Label: STRING>>,
    OriginSource        STRING
);
```

As you can see, the `LogDetails` is actually an array of structs. Sometimes its `null`, other times its an array of only 1 struct, and sometimes its an array of *dozens* of structs.

I would like to write a query against this table. I would like to search for all "Qualified" `finlog` records. A "Qualified" record is one that:

1. Has 1+ LogDetails structs in its `LogDetails` array; and
2. One of those structs has a `ControlId` matching the same record's `ClientControlNumber` field; and
3. The same struct has a `Label` value of "ACTIVE".

So for instance, an example of a "Qualified" record would be one whose `ClientControlNumber` is, say, "12345". It might have 3 structs in its `LogDetails` array, and one of those structs has a `ControlId` of "12345" **and** has a `Label` of "ACTIVE".

I would like this query to return a single column called `LogDetailsAmount`. If a record is "Qualified" using the criteria I gave above, then its `LogDetailsAmount` value would be the `LogDetailsAmount.Amount` of the `LogDetailsAmount` struct that matched. Otherwise, if a record is not qualified, its `LogDetailsAmount` value should be 0.00.

My best attempt thus far is:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM finlog AS fl
                     LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(fl.LogDetails) AS ld
                     WHERE ld.ControlId = fl.ClientControlNumber
                       AND ld.Label = "ACTIVE")
            THEN (SELECT ld.Amount
                  FROM finlog AS fl
                  LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(fl.LogDetails) AS ld
                  WHERE ld.ControlId = fl.ClientControlNumber
                    AND ld.Label = "ACTIVE"
                  LIMIT 1)
            ELSE 0.00
    END AS LogDetailAmount
FROM
    finlog AS fl;
```

I think I'm *close* but something is off.

All (and I mean **all**) values for the `LogDetailAmount` field are coming back as the same value: `-0.95`. The query returns millions of results.

I wonder if I'm matching against the same record and somehow just copying-n-pasting the same result over and over again, instead of doing the matching on a row-by-row basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your Query and I see same results as you said:

```
%sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM finlog AS fl
                     LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(fl.LogDetails) AS ld
                     WHERE ld.ControlId = fl.ClientControlNumber
                       AND ld.Label = "ACTIVE")
            THEN (SELECT ld.Amount
                  FROM finlog AS fl_inner
                  LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(fl_inner.LogDetails) AS ld
                  WHERE ld.ControlId = fl_inner.ClientControlNumber
                    AND ld.Label = "ACTIVE"
                    LIMIT 1)
            ELSE 0.00
    END AS LogDetailAmount
FROM
    finlog AS fl;
```

**Results:**

```
LogDetailAmount
55.00
55.00
55.00
55.00
```

I tried the below query:
In the below query joining on a derived table that includes rows with the '**ACTIVE**' label.
These rows are then spread out into individual records using the `OUTER EXPLODE` function.
Using `left join` all rows finlog table will be included in the output, even if there is no match in the derived table.

```
%sql
SELECT 
   CASE 
       WHEN ld_active.ControlId IS NOT NULL AND ld_active.Label = 'ACTIVE' 
       THEN ld_active.Amount 
       ELSE 0.00 
   END AS LogDetailAmount 
FROM 
   finlog AS main_fl 
   LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT 
          fl.AccountNumber, 
          ld.Amount, 
          ld.ControlId, 
          ld.Label 
       FROM 
           finlog AS fl 
           LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(fl.LogDetails) AS ld
       WHERE 
           ld.Label = 'ACTIVE'
      ) AS ld_active 
      ON main_fl.AccountNumber = ld_active.AccountNumber 
         AND ld_active.ControlId = main_fl.ClientControlNumber;
```

Results:

```
LogDetailAmount
55.00
45.00
50.00
20.00
0.00
```

- In the `CASE` Statement checking the conditions within the `WHEN` and
  `ELSE` clauses**strong text** to determine the value of **LogDetailAmount**. If
  **ld_active**.ControlId is not `null`, and **ld_active.Label** is '**ACTIVE**', then **LogDetailAmount** is set to
  **ld_active.Amount**. If the conditions are not met, it sets LogDetailAmount to **0.00**.
- `FROM` Clause specifing the source table as finlog with the alias
  **main_fl**.
- Left join with a derived table (ld_active) that contains rows
  exploded from LogDetails where the label is '**ACTIVE**'. The join
  condition ensures that the rows are matched based on AccountNumber
  and **ControlId**.
- Derived Table **(ld_active)** using `LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE` to
  `explode` the LogDetails array into separate rows for each struct.
  The `WHERE` clause filters the rows where the label is '**ACTIVE**'.
- `ON` Clause specifing the join conditions, linking the main_fl table
  with the ld_active derived table based on AccountNumber and
  ControlId.